# Unable to align bins in a histogram of datetime objects using the hist() function

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, histogram, bins

So I am trying to plot a histogram of some datetime objects, but i can never get the bins to line up with the bars. My code is below:

I start by importing my stuff and declaring the start, end and a one day object:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

end = datetime.date(2017,5,14) 
start = datetime.date(2017,5,8) 
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
```

Then I declare an arbitrary list of dates:

```
date_list = [datetime.date(2017,5,14), datetime.date(2017,5,14), 
datetime.date(2017,5,14), datetime.date(2017,5,9), datetime.date(2017,5,13), 
datetime.date(2017,5,12), datetime.date(2017,5,11), 
datetime.date(2017,5,11), datetime.date(2017,5,9)]
```

Then I go through the range of days between my start and end (in this case a week), adding each date to a list:

```
week = [] 
for i in range((end-start).days+1):  
    week.append(start + (i)*one_day)
```

The reason for this is that some of the days in the week don't come up in the date_list (I know I could just skip this for this case, but I want it to be expandable to other date_lists).

Then I plot with hist():

```
plt.hist(date_list, bins = len(week)+1)
plt.show()
```

I've tried all manner of combinations of bin formats with various +1's and ranges and aligns but the date never sit in a consistent place in the bar.

Comment: try ```plt.hist(date_list, bins = len(week)+1, align='left')```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If simply setting the number of bins, the bins will be equally distributed between the first and last value (of the data). Since the data is e.g. missing the `start` value, the bins will be smaller than a complete day.

To overcome this, one need to explicitely set the desired bins to the `bins` argument of `hist`. Unfortunately, one cannot directly use the list of datetimes here, so the datetimes need to be converted to numbers first. This can be done using matplotlib's `matplotlib.dates.date2num` method.

The complete example:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

end = datetime.date(2017,5,14) 
start = datetime.date(2017,5,8) 
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)  

date_list = [datetime.date(2017,5,14), datetime.date(2017,5,14), 
datetime.date(2017,5,14), datetime.date(2017,5,9), datetime.date(2017,5,13), 
datetime.date(2017,5,12), datetime.date(2017,5,11), 
datetime.date(2017,5,11), datetime.date(2017,5,9)]

week = [] 
for i in range((end-start).days+1):  
    week.append(start + (i)*one_day)

numweek = date2num(week)

plt.hist(date_list, bins = numweek, ec="k")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the `datetime.date(2017,5,14)` is part of the bin between the `(2017,5,13)` and `(2017,5,14)`, so you might want to set the enddate to 
`datetime.date(2017,5,15)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been tearing my hair about about this