# python, pandas, numpy, range() for datetime for histogram with discrete values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to plot a histogram of datetime values with discrete values. I.e. the events per day for certain range of days. The entries are discrete, so I would like to ensure the binning always contains the same number of discrete values. 
Something along [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112420/histogram-for-discrete-values-with-matplotlib) lines.

```
## data is a pandas.DataFrame
## data['DTM'] contains datetimes

min_date = data.DTM.dt.date.min()
max_date = data.DTM.dt.date.max()

n_days = (max_date - min_date ).days

# each bin should contain one day
bins = np.arange(min_date, max_date + 1, 1)

data.DTM.dt.date.hist(range=(min_date, max_date), bins=bins)
```

this fails because `max_date` and `min_date` are datetime objects and `np.arange` needs integers. Is there a convenient function that does the same as `range()` or `numpy.arange()` with dates?

Or is there a more elegant way to solve this?

I tried `pd.date_range(min_date, max_date + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).date` however, passing this to pd.data.hist() results in an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.date'
```

Comment: Maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43954182)

Comment: There was an answer with `pd.date_range(min_date, max_date + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).date` which was a good starting point. Even if it did not work with the pandas histogram.

Comment: Be free add to question ;)

Comment: Can you show some data? What's wrong with something like `df.set_index('DTM').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).hist()`?

Comment: That does not do the trick. It generates a plot for each day.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that does to the trick. And it does not mess up the xticks!
Thanks to Stev!

```
tmp = data[['DTM']].set_index('DTM')
tmp['Count'] = 1
tmp.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).count()
plt.bar(tmp.index, tmp.Count)
```